# How to update the subdocument of mongodb Collection using java

Tags: java, mongodb

How can i update the ptconfig with some json file using JAVA

```
{
  "_id" : "1",
  "name" : "kiran",
  "status" : "online",
  "description" : "process 1",
  "ptConfig" : {
      "xms" : 232,
      "xmx" : 233
  }
}
```

Comment: update(new BasicDBObject("_id",1),new BasicDbObject("$set",new BasicDBObject("ptConfig",new BasicDBObject("xms",newVlue).append("xms",newValue))),false,false)        Think this will work

Comment: is it in mongodb or java? y would u tag mongodb then

Comment: Is there a way, where we can update the whole ptconfig with the json file which we pass?

Comment: Basically the issue is , we pass the json file and it should update the subdocument(ptconfig) of a collection in mongodb

Comment: Either u have to update after inserting into mongodb using the above query i sent or u will have to change using java before u insert into mongo